# INSERT TRIGGERS SQL. How to retrieve value from another table after insert in new table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench, database-trigger

I am new to SQL triggers. I am currently stuck with the question below.

I have **3** tables -

1. **orders**

   orderid *int(11) AI PK* 
    orderdate *date* 
    total *decimal(8,2)*
2. **products**

   productid *int(11) AI PK* 
    productname *varchar(50)* 
    unit *varchar(10)* 
    price *decimal(8,2)*
3. **orderdetails**

   orderid int(11) 
    productid int(11) 
    price decimal(8,2)

I have records in both **orders** and **products** tables.
The **orderdetails** table is empty, no records.

I want to create an insert trigger on **orderdetails** to automatically retrieve the price from **products** table and update it into the **orderdetails** table whenever i insert a query like;

(e.g. INSERT INTO orderdetails(orderid,productid) values(1,1)) into the **orderdetails** table.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don'thave MySQL at hand but this housld work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_price BEFORE INSERT ON orderdetails
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
           SET new.price= (select price from products where productid = new.productid);
       END;//
```